# Database field name is setting while retrieving the data in android?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

While inserting a values in to database which is inserting properly.But while trying to retrieve that value the database field name is getting.The following code i have done so far,

```
  String REPORT_PROBLEM_DATABASE_LIST = "create table if not exists " + REPORT_PROBLEM_DATABASE_LIST_TABLE_NAME + "(_id integer primary key autoincrement,userId text not null,storeId text not null,machineDeviceId text not null,machineName text not null,machineIp text not null,softwareId text not null,contentDescDetails text not null,gps text not null,attachments text not null)";
    db.execSQL(REPORT_PROBLEM_DATABASE_LIST);

    public static void ReportProblemDatabaseListAddToDB(SQLiteDatabase db, ContentValues values, String userId, String storeId, String machineDeviceId, String machineName, String machineIp, String softwareId,String contentDescDetails,String gps,String attachments) {
    values.put("userId", userId);
    values.put("storeId", storeId);
    values.put("machineDeviceId", machineDeviceId);
    values.put("machineName", machineName);
    values.put("machineIp", machineIp);
    values.put("softwareId", softwareId);
    values.put("contentDescDetails",contentDescDetails);
    values.put("gps",gps);
    values.put("attachments",attachments);
    db.insert(Database.REPORT_PROBLEM_DATABASE_LIST_TABLE_NAME, null, values);
}
```

In my button click am inserting the values,

```
if (!db.isOpen()) {
                                    DBHelper = new Database(getActivity(), "Database", null, 1);
                                    db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                                }
                                reportProblemDatabaseModelsList.clear();
                                String descriptions = rp_descriptionET.getText().toString();
                                String attachments = String.valueOf(attachmentModelsList);
                                ReportProblemDatabaseModel reportProblemDatabaseModel = new ReportProblemDatabaseModel(UserID, storeIdSpValue,
                                        machineDeviceIdSend, machineNameAT.getText().toString(),
                                        rp_ipET.getText().toString(), softWareIdSend, descriptions,
                                        gpsSend, attachments);
                                reportProblemDatabaseModelsList.add(reportProblemDatabaseModel);
                                String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM REPORT_PROBLEM_DATABASE_LIST_TABLE";
                                Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
                                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                                DBUtil.ReportProblemDatabaseListAddToDB(db, values, UserID, storeIdSpValue, machineDeviceIdSend,
                                        machineNameAT.getText().toString(), rp_ipET.getText().toString(), softWareIdSend, descriptions, gpsSend, attachments);
                                db.close();
                                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ReportProblemDatabaseActivity.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
```

While retrieving the data,

```
    public void savedItems() {
        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM REPORT_PROBLEM_DATABASE_LIST_TABLE";
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                String UserID = cursor.getString(1);
                String storeIdSpValue = cursor.getString(2);
                String machineDeviceIdSend = cursor.getString(3);
                String machineName = cursor.getString(4);
                String machineIp = cursor.getString(5);
                String softWareIdSend = cursor.getColumnName(6);
                String description = cursor.getColumnName(7);
                Log.e("descriptionDb",description);
                String gps = cursor.getColumnName(8);
                String attachments = cursor.getColumnName(9);
//                String attachmentsLists = String.valueOf(attachmentsList);
                ReportProblemDatabaseModel reportProblemDatabaseModel = new ReportProblemDatabaseModel(UserID, storeIdSpValue,
                        machineDeviceIdSend, machineName,
                        machineIp, softWareIdSend, description,
                        gps, attachments);
                reportProblemDatabaseModelsList.add(reportProblemDatabaseModel);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }


    }
```

And my screenshot,
[image]

Comment: So what is the problem? Are you getting any error logs?

Comment: is `cursor.getColumnName(7);` the culprit?

Comment: From the softwareId am getting the value as particular field name..please check on my screenshot my description value as the particular field name am getting.That is my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getColumnName(int)) , `cursor.getColumnName()` returns

> The column name at the given zero-based column index.

Thus, replace

```
String description = cursor.getColumnName(7);
```

with

```
String description = cursor.getString(7);
```

Comment: Ya its my mistake.Thank you.

Comment: I have another doubt in this.Can you able to see that delete icon.I tried to delete the particular item from the db.Which is not removing why?

Comment: remove the element from your xml file.

Comment: I have done something like this,ReportProblemDatabaseModel album = albumList.get(position);
                String delgrp="DELETE FROM REPORT_PROBLEM_DATABASE_LIST_TABLE WHERE _id='"+album+"'";
                db.execSQL(delgrp);
                ReportProblemDatabaseActivity.reportProblemDatabaseModelsList.remove(position);
                ReportProblemDatabaseActivity.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Answer (score 1):

```java
            String description = cursor.getColumnName(7);
```

`getColumnName()` gets the name of the column.

To get the value in the eighth column, you have to use `getString(7)`.

Comment: Ya its my mistake.Thank you.